# AssertionError: PermissionDenied not raised

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to testing in django , i'm trying to test a view that raises PermissonDenied when the test user is not authenticated , this is part of the view code

```
@login_required
def files_raw(request):
    user = request.user  # Get the current user

    # Initialize the base SQL query
    base_sql_query = ""

    # Check user conditions
    if user.is_superuser:
        # If the user is a superuser, they can access all data, so no need to change the base query.
        base_sql_query = "SELECT * FROM files"
    elif user.groups.filter(name='RNA').exists():
        # User is in the 'RNA' group, update the base query to include 'RNA'.
        base_sql_query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE files.Sample_id LIKE '%RNA'"
    elif user.groups.filter(name='WGS').exists():
        # User is in the 'WGS' group, update the base query to exclude 'RNA'.
        base_sql_query = " SELECT * FROM files WHERE files.Sample_id NOT LIKE '%RNA'"
    else:
     # If none of the conditions are met, raise a PermissionDenied with a custom error message.
        print("DEBUG: Conditions not met for user:", user) 
        raise PermissionDenied("You are not authorized to access this data")

    # Execute the raw SQL query
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(base_sql_query)
        # Initialize an empty list to store the results
        files = []
        
        # Iterate over the cursor to fetch one row at a time
        for row in cursor:
            # Process the row
            file_id, file_name, file_size_gb, md5, sample_value, url = row
            # You can process the row data here or append it to the 'files' list
            files.append({
                'file_id': file_id,
                'file_name': file_name,
                'file_size_gb': file_size_gb,
                'md5': md5,
                'sample_value': sample_value,
                'url': url
            })
            
    # Create a context dictionary with the files list and pass it to the template
    context = {'files': files}
    return render(request, 'files_list.html', context)
```

In which I send base_sql_query to the database based on the group of the user.
So, in the test part I started with a test for an unauthenticated user , the code is down below

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


class FilePageTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create a user without necessary permissions
        self.no_permissions_user = User.objects.create_user(username='no_permissions_user', password='password')

        # Create a group (e.g., 'NoPermissionsGroup')
        self.no_permissions_group = Group.objects.create(name='NoPermissionsGroup')

        # Add the user to the group
        self.no_permissions_user.groups.add(self.no_permissions_group)

    def test_unauthenticated_access(self):
        # Log in with the user without permissions
        self.client.login(username='no_permissions_user', password='password')

        # Print user information for debugging
        print("DEBUG: User groups:", self.no_permissions_user.groups.all())

        # Test that accessing the URL raises a PermissionDenied with a custom error message
        with self.assertRaises(PermissionDenied):
            response = self.client.get("/file/")
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

So, basically i can't see why the test would raise the following error

```
AssertionError: PermissionDenied not raised
```

the origin of the error is the last line of the test which is

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this error it would be much appreciated :)

all details are described above.

Comment: What do your debug prints put out?

Comment: it prints this message
`DEBUG: User groups: <QuerySet [<Group: NoPermissionsGroup>]`

Comment: The debug print from `files_raw` is never reached then? Is `files_raw` reached at all? Maybe the request never gets to `files_raw`, because of other issues like URL configuration? Can you debug with your IDE (that would make this a **LOT** easier)?

Comment: Debugging with vscode this error raises at the import statement level 
```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```

Comment: Are you running the tests using the Django's `test` command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial05/#running-tests

Comment: Yes, I'm running 
`python manage.py test`
or 
`python manage.py test myapp.tests.test_views`
since i have multiple tests files in the same directory tests.

Comment: Where is that `ImproperlyConfigured` exception being raised? In what module? Maybe, in your code, you are importing a module that messes with the settings before they have been configured.

Comment: It is raised when i try to import
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group`
ps: the django.contrib.auth is already added to the list of apps in settings.py

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of that `ImproperlyConfigured` error to your question above.

Comment: Ok, I did add the missing import statements to the original question above :)

Comment: No, I meant the stack trace of the error. https://realpython.com/python-traceback/

Comment: `Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
  File "/home/wael/django-conectaml/conect/conect/tests/test_views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`